# Finding S parameters from Z parameters

Tags: network

How do I find S parameters from Z parameters, for a two port network.

I am sorry to ask such an elementary question but I am not from an engineering background. I have tried to search answers online but could not find it.

Comment: See if this helps. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impedance_parameters#Relation_to_S-parameters   A text book is given as reference. See if you can get a hold of that book.

Comment: https://www.rfcafe.com/references/electrical/s-h-y-z.htm

Comment: Here’s [another website](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/9780470768020.app4) ... so what were you searching for in order to get no results or results you didn’t like?

Comment: I think this is a great question, if we don't have a duplicate someone should provide an answer and document the answer here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This table gives the relationship between S, Z, Y and ABCD parameters. It's from David Pozar's "Microwave Engineering", 4th edition, page 192. If you are interested on the details, you can consult the book.

[image: Table 4.2 from Pozar]

Comment: Though the answer does not explain how the transformation is made, but I accept it.

Comment: @ChetanWaghela Z parameters relate currents to voltages. To do the transformation you must find the relationship between currents, voltages and incident and reflected power waves. I will add it to the answer later.